# What is the best way to generate node(book) to ePub?

Tags: files, nodes

I want to create a Journal site that can generate book(node) to ePub, like [Open Journal Systems(OJS)](https://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/). So what is the best way to generate node to ePub? I have tried [Printer](https://drupal.org/project/print), but it only show the following error messages on iBook. File generated by [PHPePub](https://github.com/Grandt/PHPePub)(Printer) can open by Calibre, but all images are missing.

> **This page contains the following errors:**
>
> error on line 47 at column 27: AttValue: " or ' expected 
>   **Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

Comment: sorry, you probably won't like this, but:
With the information currently contained in the question, I see no reason to think this is related to Drupal. Either it's a bug in the epub library, in which case the question is off topic, or the print module passes bad data to the epub library, in which case it's a module bug and thus off-topic. I can't vote to close on a bountied question, but that seems to be the correct thing to do here.

Comment: H-L does state the content is "book(node)"  This sounds explicitly Drupal to me.

Comment: @Gold yes Gold, it's "book" content type from book module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this answer is dead simple, but have you tried [EPUB Export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/epub_export)?

> This project builds content objects from drupal and bundles them into an
>   EPUB 3.0 document. Currently it will export a rendered entity seperate of all
>   of the page markup and gather all the referenced resources within the content
>   and bundle those into one EPUB document.

I tested it on a clean install and it appears to work as advertised.

Comment: I know it's development stalled at 2013-Sep-30, but I think it's a pretty solid base to start - OP is perfectly willing to edit Drupal code for interaction with 3rd party libraries (in his question he says he did it already), so probably he will be able to work with bugs, if he will encounter any.

Comment: EPUB Export module require to Run Cron in order to build the process, and still not able to open by iBooks. Anyway, this module is a better ePub generator and does contain images when I opening by Calibre. Thank you Mołot.

Comment: @H-L the problem with epub format, generally, is that there is a LOT of versions, and not all features are supported on all devices, etc, etc. On the other hand, mobi is more limited. Way more limited. So are mobi's compatibility problems ;)